# Plus-que-parfait ou non ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subordonnées, infinitif

Laquelle des deux phrases suivantes est la meilleure grammaticalement?

Avec plus-que-parfait ?

> J'avais ressenti que j'étais un arbitre à plein temps.

Ou sans plus-que-parfait ?

> J'ai ressenti que j'étais un arbitre à plein temps.

À mon avis, la 2ème phrase est meilleure parce qu'on parle du même pronom *je*.

Comment: Il y a deux différences entre la première phrase et la seconde. Le temps du premier verbe, et l'emploi d'une proposition infinitive ou d'une subordonée. À priori contrairement à ce que le titre peut laisser penser, c'est la deuxième différence qui t'intéresse ?

Comment: Personnellement, les 2 sonnent faux pour moi. Dans la 2ème, ce qui me gène c'est l'enchainement "ressentais être"... La proposition du passé composé de @Nairolf21 est la plus naturelle à mon avis.

Comment: Elles s'utilisent dans des contextes différents. L'une pour du présent dans le passé (2), l'autre pour du passé dans le passé (1). Il faudrait un contexte pour répondre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La deuxième. Elle se dit beaucoup mieux. La première n'est quasiment jamais utilisée.

Answer (score 4):

La première phrase utilise le plus-que-parfait qui ne s'emploie que très rarement. Ici, la phrase ne justifie pas cette utilisation.

Par contre, tu peux utiliser le `passé composé` qui donnera un sens un peu différent de la seconde phrase (qui est très correcte grammaticalement).

> J'ai ressenti que j'étais un arbitre à plein temps.

En utilisant le `passé composé`, tu insistes sur le fait que tu as eu ce sentiment à un *instant particulier et précis*. Suivant le contexte, cela peut être quelque chose comme :

> Après ce match, j'ai ressenti que j'étais un arbitre à plein temps.

La seconde phrase fait plutôt référence à un sentiment qui *dure dans le temps*